# How are instance methods converted to delegates?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, closures

It seems simple enough how static methods are invoked in delegates, as all of their parameters will be passed to them when the delegate itself is invoked.
However when an instance method is added to a delegate, the 'this' parameter is seemingly ignored during the invocation of the delegate, and so I can only imagine that it is saved alongside the delegate itself - similar to what a closure can do with other parameters.

**Q:** Will a closure be created by the compiler when an instance method is passed to a delegate, or is there a different mechanism by which this is accomplished?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/open-delegates-vs-closed-delegates.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

The `Delegate` class has a `Target` property which stores the value of `this` to pass when calling the method.
In other words, a `Delegate` actually stores *two* things: A function pointer and a value for the first parameter.

A delegate that contains a target is called a *closed delegate*, since it closes over the first parameter.

In fact, this is actually, how closures work.  When the compiler creates a closure for a delegate, it will create a class that holds the variables that are closed over, and store that class as the delegate's `Target`.

For more information, see my blog posts:

- http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/open-delegates-vs-closed-delegates.html
- http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-4-c.html

Comment: True, and `Target` can be any object (not necessarily `this` in some sense), like if you say `Func<string, bool> f = "abcdef".StartsWith;`. Of course, for a static method `Target` is `null`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: `Target` is (almost) always passed as the _method's_ `this` parameter. I did not mean to imply that its value is `this`.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the (underlying) Delegate class. It defines a member called `Target` which defines the instance. In case of a static method `Target` is associated with the class itself.